# Inserting date from java to Oracle DB

Tags: java, oracle

I was trying to insert a value into one of the columns with DATE datatype in Oracle DB through java.

Tried with the below

`insertSurveyQuery.append("cast(to_date('12/31/8888', 'MM/dd/yyyy' )as date), ");`

**OP in Oracle DB:**

DEC-31-88

but i want the date to be stored like 12/31/8888.

Any of your help is appreciated!

-Thanks!

Comment: That just looks like a formatting issue when Oracle displays the date back to you. The data should be okay (I'd double-check the year, though, 8888 is a bit extreme...)

Comment: A `date` column does ***NOT*** have a "format". The SQL client (the application) formats the date value when displaying it. Just change the display format of dates in your SQL client.

Comment: i guess you need to change the default date format of your oracle client

Comment: @Thilo : yes that year is too extreme but that is the data we got :)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name and upog : Thanks! Modified in the oracle client so it works fine :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how your SQL client display dates. You can alter this format by using:

`alter session set NLS_DATE_FORMAT='MM/dd/yyyy';`

Internally (in DB) DATE is stored numerically so it doesn't have any format.

Comment: yes i worked in the same way by setting this for both date and timestamp for each session.now modified the date format in oracle client so it works fine now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you have many users accessing your application, then you could do the following in Java code

```
Date newDate = new SimpleDateFormat("mm/dd/yyyy").parse(myDate);
```

and use `newDate` in insert or update statement.

By doing this you do not need to change client settings.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to create table in the format of

```
create table t1
(
ename varchar(20),
address varchar(20),
hire_date date,
salary number(5),
dob (we enter as 'dd-mm-yyyy')
);
```

In which you will have to give the date column as `dd-mm-yyyy` type then you can set data as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle doesn't support the format of DD/MM/YYYY. If you want to store the date time or time stamp you have to use DD-MM-YYYY format.

In direct insert query:

```
  SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy' 'hh:mm:ss a");  
     String date = "01-01-1900 01:00:00 AM";
```

In Procedure :

```
create or replace 
PROCEDURE insertDATE(
        DATE_PARAM IN VARCHAR2,
         )
IS
 BEGIN 

 INSERT INTO CUSTOMER("DATE")
  VALUES (TO_TIMESTAMP(DATE_PARAM,'DD-MM-YYYY HH:MI:SS AM'));
  COMMIT;
  END;
```