# How to save date to oracle

Tags: java, oracle, date

I want to save date to oracle from eclipse java program.
Right now I am using this code

```
    DateFormat dt=new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    java.sql.Date dob=(java.sql.Date)dt.parse("02/02/2015");
    ob.setDateOfBirth(dob);
```

The table has a column named Date_of_birth having date datatype.

But i am getting an error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: 
java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.sql.Date
at com.TestCustomerDao.main(TestCustomerDao.java:22)
```

Please Help

Comment: `dt.parse("02/02/2015");` this method will return `java.util.Date` object. you can use that one only..

Comment: Other duplicates and similar: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18893863/642706), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24652571/642706), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28292468/642706), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2942270/642706), and **most importantly**, [java.util.Date vs java.sql.Date](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2305973/642706).

Answer (score 1):

The class that `DateFormat.parse(String)` returns is `java.util.Date`.

You need a `java.sql.Date`, which is actually a subclass of the above. You can only cast an object *up* to a class it inherits from, you can't cast *down* to a class that inherits from it.

In order to do that properly, you need to create a new `java.sql.Date` object from the `java.util.Date` object by using:

```
java.sql.Date dob = new java.sql.Date( dt.parse("02/02/2015").getTime() );
```

This gets the internal time stamp (representation of time as milliseconds since January 1970) from the `java.util.Date` object, and creates a `java.sql.Date` that is based on the same time stamp.